# How can I change the configuration settings for all the packages at one go in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, upgrade, dts, msbi

I am migrating an SSIS solution from one data center to another. The existing packages are of 2008 version. I have upgraded them to 2017. Now I have to test them in Test server before moving them to production. The connections are all dynamic and they are fetching the server name and paths from SSISConfigurations table. I have changed the values in the table in Test server and updated the variables in the Master package.

I was told that is all I need to change and the same variables which are used for the child packages will be automatically updated. But after executing the master package I found that the change is reflected only in master package. The connections(variables) of other packages are still unchanged.

How can I can configure the connections of all the packages at one go? There are more than 60 packages so doing them manually is out of question. Please keep in mind I am still pretty new to MSBI.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i didn't need to to do all the packages at one go as it seemed. All I had to do was update the SSISConfigurations table and the the configuration was updated. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implemented the migration, I mention this out because that might be the problem for your SSISConfigurations table.
Maybe somehow the configuration erased from the "package configuration organizer"?
[package configuration organizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbKK0.png)

Anyway, the answer you're looking for is here.
[Applying SSIS Package Configuration to multiple packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547304/applying-ssis-package-configuration-to-multiple-packages)

Comment: First I migrated the solution to 2012 version and then to 2017. The SSISConfigurations table in the test environment is a direct replica of the SSISConfigurations table of the Production environment. I just changed the values which were pointing towards production. I will go through the links you just provided in your answer and will let you know if it worked. Thank you

Comment: well i didn't need to to do all the packages at one go as it seemed. All I had to do was update the SSISConfigurations table and the the configuration was updated. Thanks for your suggestion